# OutOfMemoryError android m

Tags: android

Okay, I'm new to Android and have this little problem that I can't seen to find an answer to. I know that this is a common error but all the other threads that I found aren't helpful to me, so I had to create my own.

I'm simply using a listview, and have an Adaptor. The error occurs suddenly when scrolling up and down through the listview items, without even clicking on the items.

Here are some of the logs:

> D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
>
> D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 173K, 36% free 17008K/26172K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
>
> I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 31.092MB for 10760416-byte allocation
>
> D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called
>
> D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called
>
> D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called
>
> I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 61.836MB for 33177616-byte allocation
>
> D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 52K, 14% free 59979K/69088K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
>
> I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 79.593MB for 18662416-byte allocation
>
> D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 11% free 78200K/87316K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
>
> I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 111.230MB for 33177616-byte allocation
>
> D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10515K, 15% free 101867K/119720K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
>
> I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 16104976-byte allocation
>
> D/dalvikvm: GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 15K, 15% free 101851K/119720K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
>
> E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 16104976-byte allocation.

.

> Shutting down VM
>
> W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418ceda0)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   Process: com.example.hesham.assignment2, PID: 24883
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
>   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3024)
>   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1586)
>   at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16144)
>   at com.example.hesham.assignment2.myAdaptor.getView(myAdaptor.java:47)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2694)
>   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1811)
>   at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
>   at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:661)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:6686)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3946)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:4789)
>   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4617)
>   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8107)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2129)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
>   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
>   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2280)
>   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1615)
>   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2544)
>   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:268)
>   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2228)
>   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8315)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4598)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4466)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4024)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4078)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4047)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4158)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4055)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4215)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4024)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4078)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4047)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4055)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4024)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6416)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6320)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6291)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6256)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:649

And there's a an highlighted line, which refers to a line in my Adaptor.

> y2.setBackgroundResource(items[i].img);

And here's my whole Adaptor

```
public class myAdaptor extends BaseAdapter{
Data items[];
Context context;
TextView y;
ImageView y2;
myAdaptor(Data items[], Context context)
{
    this.items=items;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View x=view;
    if(x==null)
    {
        x=View.inflate(context,R.layout.item,null);
    }
    y=(TextView) x.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    y2=(ImageView) x.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    y.setText(items[i].str1);
    y2.setBackgroundResource(items[i].img);

    return x;
}}
```

So I can't find why I keep getting this error, and I'm not using a bitmap which I found all the other threads are using. So any ideas on how to fix this?
Please let me know if I need to update the thread with any of my code.
Sorry for the long post, and thank you.

Comment: are you loading images from web via some api ?

Comment: reduce the size or images you are loading. they must be heavy in size thats why outOfMemoryError is coming

Comment: shuvro; No, from my pc.
@Sangeeta I'm using 6 images, and they are 400kb. However, I'm using 21 song which are 188mb, but I don't think that's a problem as it makes the app 190mb, so it should work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Create a folder named `drawable-nodpi` inside your res folder . Put all of your images there .

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thanks alot, but could you explain what's the difference or what's nodpi please?

Comment: glad it helped, the reason behind this your images tried to scale according to your device density. If you put images in drawable-nodpi then it won't try to scale any images according to device density. If it solves your problem then you should accept the answer.